# Cut every element of a vector of strings at the second occurrence of a pattern in R

Tags: r, stringr, substr

I have a chr vector:

```
> head(strings)
[1] "10_88517_0"  "10_88521_1"  "10_88542_2"  "10_280230_3" "10_280258_4" "10_280310_5"
```

I want to create a new vector of substrings, obtained by cutting each element of this vector at the second `_`.  E.g.:

```
> head(cut_strings)
[1] "10_88517"  "10_88521"  "10_88542"  "10_280230" "10_280258" "10_280310"
```

My idea was to first grep for the position of second `_` in each string:

```
cut_pts <- sapply(stringr::str_locate_all(strings, "_"), "[", 2)
```

All I can come up with though is an awkward for loop that goes through the `strings` vector and calls `substr` for each element, e.g.:

```
cut_strings <- strings
for(i in 1:length(strings)){
  string <- strings[i]
  cut_pt <- cut_pts[i]
  string <- substr(string, 1, cut_pt-1)
  cut_strings[i] <- string
}
```

I'm thinking maybe there's a way to use `apply` in this context, to cut each element of `strings` based on the appropriate element of `cut_pts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could capture those characters in `sub` and remove the substring afterwards i..e below pattern matches the one or more characters not an underscore (`[^_]+`) followed by an underscore, then characters not an underscore and remove the character starting from second underscore by not including in the capture group (`(...)`).  Note that we specified the start of the string (`^`).  In the replacement, use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*", "\\1", strings)
```